# Invalid argument(s): clientId.refreshToken cannot be null with flutter google api

Tags: flutter, google-api

I want to keep logging in, but I understand that the accessToken is only valid for up to an hour, and I also understand that I need a refreshToken.
But I don't know how to get a refreshToken, it seems that GoogleSignInAuthentication only has accessToken and idToken.
https://github.com/google/googleapis.dart/blob/master/googleapis_auth/lib/src/access_credentials.dart

Can someone please advise me on this?